# Unable to create side-by-side bars

Tags: tableau-api

Attached are screenshots of my data and measures attempting to create a side-by-side visualization. 
[image: Data]

[image: Dash]

Comment: It appears as though your months are separate dimensions, correct? If so, you'll want to pivot them into a since continuous date field, then you'll be able to chart bars by month.

If this doesn't solve your problem, it would be helpful if you could share a copy of the workbook.

Comment: Do you mean pivot them into a 'single' continuous date field? Can this be done in Tableau or does the underlying data need to be changed?

Comment: @Chris Tableau has some data prep capabilities, including pivoting.  Take a look at https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/pivot.html.  If you can provide a mockup or more detailed description of the behavior you are expecting the in the form of a question.  That would also help in answering.

Answer (score 0):

My date fields were located under Dimensions. I had to drag them to Measures and change the data type. This allowed me to create a side-by-side chart.